# auto refresh ajax hides class bot not id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Okey, i have a functions.php that handles some functions.

one is the `function comment_func_bar`.

This function outputs `No likes · Like · Report` at the bottom of every comment to posts.

I have sendlike.php that handles the mysql data.

```
    <?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("config.php");
//Include functions
include_once("functions.php");


// For practice
    $uid_fk = 1;

//check $_POST["content_txt"] is not empty
if(isset($_GET["like"]) && strlen($_GET["like"])>0) 
{   

    //Add IP, date. Set the Foreign key
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $comment_id_fk = $_GET["like"]; // '".$comment_id_fk."', What comment has been liked?

    // $_SESSION["user_id"]  '".$uid_fk."', What user has liked it? Get the users uid

    // Insert sanitize string in record
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO comment_likes (comment_id_fk, uid_fk,date,ip)
        VALUES('".$comment_id_fk."','".$uid_fk."','".$date."','".$ip."')");

    if($insert_row)
    {
        //Count the amount of likes again
        $count_likes=$mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTAL_COMMENT_LIKES FROM `comment_likes` 
        WHERE comment_id_fk='".$comment_id_fk."'");
        $row_array=$count_likes->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

       $mysqli->close(); //close db connection
// header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //ADD
    }else{

        //header('HTTP/1.1 500 '.mysql_error()); //display sql errors.. must not output sql errors in live mode.
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
        exit();
    }

}
elseif(isset($_GET["delike"]) && strlen($_GET["delike"])>0 && is_numeric($_GET["delike"]))
{   //do we have a delete request? $_POST["recordToDelete"]

    //sanitize post value, PHP filter FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT removes all characters except digits, plus and minus sign.
    $idToDelete = filter_var($_GET["delike"],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 

    //try deleting record using the record ID we received from POST
    $delete_row = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM comment_likes WHERE comment_id_fk='".$idToDelete."' AND uid_fk ='".$uid_fk."'"); //uid_fk is $_SESSION[user_id] actually

    if(!$delete_row)
    {    
        //If mysql delete query was unsuccessful, output error 
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Could not delete record!');
        exit();
    }
    $mysqli->close(); //close db connection
  //  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //ADD
}
else
{
    //Output error
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error occurred, Could not process request!');
    exit();
}
?>
```

And i want to do this with AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('click', '.clickable', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var action =  $(this).html();
                // var comment_id = this.id;
                var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');
                if(action == 'Like')
                {
                    var data ={like:comment_id};
                }
                else
                {
                    var data ={delike:comment_id};
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "sendlike.php",
                    data:data,
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(response){ 
                    $(".clickable").hide();
                    $(".clickable").append(response);
                    $(".clickable").fadeIn();
                    },
                 error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
                             }

            });
            });
 </script>
```

After click Like (or Unlike) the amount of likes should auto refresh and Like should change to Unlike.

The `comment_fun_bar` handles this when I'm not using Ajax.

```
  echo '<p id="txtHint"><small>' . $how_many .' <a href="#" class="clickable" id="'.$comment_id .'">Like</a> · <a href="">Report</a>'.$owner.'</small></p>';
 }
 else 
 {
     echo '<p id="txtHint"><small>' . $how_many .' <a href="#" class="clickable" id="'.$comment_id .'">Unlike</a> · <a href="">Report</a>'.$owner.'</small></p>';
 }
```

Inserting to DB works, but not the auto refresh. And it also hides and fadeIn all of the comments with the class="clickable". Can someone pleas help me with this.

It seems that i somehow need to also hide the href id inside the Ajax function. But don't really know how. Was trying to use #comment_id, but with no luck.

Comment: First, You have to hide and fade the comment for the corresponding id, not all the comments with the `clickable` class.  Second, you can generate the `HTML` code regarding to the status of the comment(like or dislike) in the `sendlike.php` file and echo it back. then pars the response in the `axaj` and show the correct links after the success response.

Answer (score 0):

Change ajax to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('click', '.clickable', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var action =  $(this).html();
                var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');
                if(action == 'Like')
                {
                    var data ={like:comment_id};
                    var status="Unlike";

                }
                else
                {
                    var data ={delike:comment_id};
                    var status = "Like";
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "sendlike.php",
                    data:data,
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(response){ 
                    $(".txtHint_"+comment_id).hide();
                    $(".txtHint_"+comment_id).html("");
                    $(".txtHint_"+comment_id).append(response).fadeIn();
                    },
                 error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
                             }

            });
            });
 </script>
```

And took advice form @EhsanT about sendlike.php